# How to set custom permissions on /dev/ttyS0 so that they persist after reboot?

Tags: permissions, devices, tty, serial-port

After every reboot I have to set `chmod o+rw /dev/ttyS0` to be able to print to my POS printer via serial port in `bash`.

Is it possible to save permissions and also baud rate, bits, stop bit and parity after the device is closed?

Comment: what is the result of `ls /dev/ttyS0`?

Comment: In many Linux distributions the entire `/dev` subtree is not persistent, but it is generated at boot by `udev`.

Comment: @richard `crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 Sij 17 09:15 /dev/ttyS0` after boot and then I change it to `crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 4, 64 Sij 17 09:15 /dev/ttyS0` that I can print from bash

Comment: Add yourself to group `dialout`, it is also more secure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can check the group owner of /dev/ttyS0 with:

```
ls -l /dev/ttyS0
```

and then add your user in this group:

```
usermod -a -G {group-name} username
```

Comment: ... as long as one isn't on one of the operating systems where serial terminals have group `wheel`.  This hasn't answered what the questioner asked about line speed and framing, by the way.

Comment: Btw. `useradd` is for a new user. I am an existing user. I have to use `sudo usermod -a -G dialout my_username`. Then I can confirm it with the command `groups my_username`. I just found this because `useradd` didn't work

Comment: @HrvojeT you are right. Changed the command above too.